# Multi-task regression problem using Pytorch (Problem: Same output for all test data)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, multitasking, non-linear-regression

I am trying to multi-task regression problem.

Input shape: 200 * 60000, Output shape: 200*3 (here, 200 = Total number of data, 60000 = number of features)

So, for each data point, I have to predict 3 values (continuous).

Sample Code:

```
    
class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_nodes):
        super(Classifier, self).__init__()
        self.input_nodes = input_nodes
        
        self.sharedlayer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_nodes, 300),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(300, 100),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(),
        )
        
        
        self.att1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 40),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(40, 20),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(20, 1)
        )
        self.att2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 40),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(40, 20),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(20, 1)
        )
        self.att3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 40),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(40, 20),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(20, 1)
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        
        h_shared = self.sharedlayer(x)
        out1 = self.att1(h_shared)
        out2 = self.att2(h_shared)
        out3 = self.att3(h_shared)
        
        return out1, out2, out3

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
            running_loss = 0
            i = 0
            model.train()
            for data, label in trainloader:
                 i = i + 1
                 out1, out2, out3 = model(data)
                 
                 
                 l1 = criterion(out1, label[:,0].view(-1,1))    
                 l2 = criterion(out2, label[:,1].view(-1,1))
                 l3 = criterion(out3, label[:,2].view(-1,1))    
                 
                 loss = (l1 + l2 + l3)
                 optimizer.zero_grad()
                 loss.backward()
                 optimizer.step()
```

> > Problem: The model always produces same value for all test data.
>
> Example: Suppose, 3 Test data:
>
> For output1: 3.5 3.5 3.5
>
> For output2: 9.5 9.5 9.5
>
> For output3: 0.2 0.2 0.2

Can you please help me to figure out what is the problem here?

Why does it generate the same value for all test data?

Comment: You can use `torch.nn.MSELoss` directly, no need to slice. Check if it works this way

Comment: @SzymonMaszke, Thanks for your suggestion. But it does not work. The same problem is still there.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code where  you are defining your optimizer?  Are you providing it with all parameters? I think initially all three outputs could be similar, but after some iterations they should diverge according to label.

Comment: @UsmanAli, optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
Not all the three outputs are same. problem is: for output node1, outputs are same for all test data.

Comment: During testing, are you calling model.eval() in order to ignore Dropout layers? I can not spot any issues otherwise.

Comment: Yes, during the testing time, I called model.eval() first. @UsmanAli

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul I have repeated your experiment by  using `torch.rand(100, 6000)` as training data while the three values for `label` are  sum of first 1000, 3000 and 6000 values of input feature respectively.  For `torch.rand(5,6000)` as test data, I have got variable values for all 5 test instances for each of the output. May be the issue has to do with your dataset.

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul if values for labels are too small, you can compare them to verify if they differ in very small decimal places. Something like 0.03452167 and 0.03452179 etc.

Comment: @UsmanAli, Thanks for your suggestion.